# Can not execute commands on Redis Server with RESP

Tags: c#, sockets, redis

I am trying to send commands from a .NET Console application to a Redis instance via a socket.I do not understand why the sent commands are not applied since the bytes were sent .I have tried both with the RESP protocol and a normal command.But none get applied to the server:

```
 class Program
    {
        public static string command0 = "set a 200";
        public static string command1 = "*3\r\n$3\r\nset\r\n$1\r\na\r\n:200\r\n";

        static  void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 32772);
                await sock.ConnectAsync(point);
                await sock.SendDataAsync(command0);
                await sock.SendDataAsync(command1);
            }).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

public static class SocketExtensions
    {
        public static  async Task  SendDataAsync(this Socket socket,string message)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.ToCharArray());
            ArraySegment<byte> segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
            int rem = bytes.Length;
            while(rem>0)
            {
                int sent=await socket.SendAsync(bytes, SocketFlags.None);
                rem -= sent;
                segment.Slice(sent);
            }
        }
    }
```

The **state** of the socket before performing command:

[image]

Can it be because the encoding?

Comment: If you are building your own client, I would take a look at the [request/response protocol](https://redis.io/topics/protocol) for Redis.

Comment: Check my update.I have tried both ways.When i try to  "get a" from the cli there's nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the command:

For the command `set a 200` i was creating a RESP query:

```
*3\r\n$3\r\nset\r\n$1\r\na\r\n:200\r\n
```

The problem was that I thought the value should be sent as an integer. Instead I had to write it as a bulk string:

```
$3\r\n200\r\n
```

instead of

```
:200\r\n
```